# How do I tell gnuplot to get the array size from a variable when plotting binary?

Tags: bash, plot, gnuplot

I want to plot binary files of variable size with a gnuplot script. The script should automatically read the size of the plot from the file size. E.g. if the file is 4096 KB (= 1024 x 1024 x 4 Byte floats) the size to be used should be `binary array=1024x1024` and if it is 66 KB (= 128 x 128 x 4 Byte floats) it should be `binary array=128x128`. I can read the plotsize into a gnuplot variable named `PLOTSIZE` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p
reset

set palett gray
PLOTSIZE=`echo $(( $(du -B1 xy.bin | grep -oP "\d+")/4 ))`
PLOTSIZE=sqrt(PLOTSIZE)
print PLOTSIZE

plot 'xy.bin' binary array=PLOTSIZExPLOTSIZE with image  # <--- THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK
plot 'xy.bin' binary array=1024x1024 with image          # <--- BUT WITH A FIXED SIZE IT WORKS
```

But I don't know gnuplot's syntax to use the variable as an actual value for `array=`. Is there a solution that does not involve making a shell script out of my gnuplot script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Preferred method (newer syntax)

Use the `array=(x,y)` syntax, which as you have noted, already works with variables as well as literal values.

---

#### Older method

It's certainly not going to win any beauty contests but you could use `eval` and `sprintf` like this:

```
ps = sprintf("%dx%d", PLOTSIZE, PLOTSIZE)
eval "plot 'xy.bin' binary array=" . ps . " with image"
```

If you haven't used `eval` before, it evaluates the contents of a string as a command. `sprintf` is used to produce the string `'1024x1024'` from the variable `PLOTSIZE`, which is concatenated into the `plot` string.

Not ideal but it means that you can avoid using the deprecated syntax.

Comment: A possible candidate for a beauty contests would be `set macros; sprintf('%dx%d', PLOTSIZE, PLOTSIZE); plot 'xy.bin' binary array=@a with image`. But the syntax `(x,y)` is the recommended one, see my comment to the other answer :)

Comment: @Christoph thanks, I've modified my answer so as not to mislead. I haven't used macros before but I guess that you need to assign `@a=sprintf(...)`

Comment: My fault. You must assign `a = sprintf(...`, the `@` is required only as prefix when using the macro.

Answer (score 2):

What I found out so far is, that it works with the old (deprecated) syntax of the `plot binary array` command:

```
 plot 'xy.bin' binary array=(PLOTSIZE,PLOTSIZE) with image
```

But that is not an ideal solution, as this syntax is deprecated. Any other ideas?

Comment: You are wrong, `array=(x,y)` is the recommended syntax, and `array=3x3` is deprecated. Most probably because of exactly the same problem like you have. From the gnuplot docs: `Note:
Gnuplot version 4.2 used the syntax array=128x128 ratherthan array=(128,128). The older syntax is now deprecated, but may still work if your copy of gnuplot was built to support
backwards compatibility.`